# Setting up ruby on rails 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I decided to learn ruby on rails today. I did:

```
    gem install rails
    rails new <name>
    cd <name>
    rails server
```

Just like http://rubyonrails.org/download/ said to, and everything looked fine until I went to localhost:3000 on chrome I got "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" and got nothing server side. Then I did:

```
    wget localhost:3000
```

and got this client side (the terminal window running wget):

```
    --2016-01-16 23:08:43--  http://localhost:3000/
    Resolving localhost... fe80::1
    Connecting to localhost|fe80::1|:3000... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
    2016-01-16 23:08:43 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

and this server side (the side running rails server):

```
    Started GET "/" for fe80::1%o0 at 2016-01-16 23:08:17 -0500
```

sorry if this is obvious I am a web scrub :)

EDIT:

when I launch it says "WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=35515 port=3000" so I assume that means it's on the right port

EDIT:

development.log:

Started GET "/" for fe80::1%lo0 at 2016-01-16 23:08:17 -0500

Started GET "/" for fe80::1%lo0 at 2016-01-16 23:08:33 -0500

Started GET "/" for fe80::1%lo0 at 2016-01-16 23:08:43 -0500

Comment: Have you tried specifying the port with `rails server 3000`?

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` means your server code ran, but there was an error. Turn on logging to see the stacktrace - it will narrow down the problem to what line the error happened.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Open your hosts file and see if there is a line like this:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

Commenting it out or removing should help.

Answer (score 0):

By default running rails server will start in development mode.  So I would expect a log folder to be created with further details:

```
gem install rails
rails new <name>
cd <name>
rails server
```

Than you should be able to view the error in the log

```
<project folder>
cd log
vi development.log
```